# how to use special character in DTLloaddb keys

Tags: datatool

```
\DTLsetseparator{,}
\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={Method, Accuracy, F-Measure(\%), No. of iterations}]{table2}{GDSGD_2.csv}
```

Hi,
 I want to include special character in my column header, i am using datatool and DTLloaddb does not seem to work even if escape the special char. (here %)

The document wont compile and it throws lot of errors like Missing: \endcsname inserted.

Answer (score 1):

Without a MWE, this is untested, but from the error message you quote I would try replacing `\%` by `\safepercent` which you could define by

```
\begingroup
\lccode`\+`\%\lowercase{\endgroup\def\safepercent{+}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the one below and it worked for me. I used a dummy header in my csv file.

```
\DTLloaddb[headers={Method,\shortstack{Accuracy (\%)},\shortstack{F-Score (\%)}, No. of iterations},keys={Method, Accuracy, F-Measure, No. of iterations}]{table3}{tablecsv/GDSGD_3.csv}
```