# How to load a non-separating comma with datatool/DTLloadrawdb

Tags: symbols, datatool

I would like to load in a key,value type list using \DTLloadrawdb: `\DTLloadrawdb{vars}{"variables.txt"}`

variables.txt:

```
key,value
customerName,Acme Corp
customerAddress1,1600 Pennsylvania Ave NE
customerAddress2,Washington, DC
```

tex file:

```
\DTLloadrawdb{vars}{"variables.txt"}
\begin{document}
\DTLfetch{vars}{key}{customerName}{value}
\DTLfetch{vars}{key}{customerAddress1}{value}
\DTLfetch{vars}{key}{customerAddress2}{value}
\end{document}
```

Unsurprisingly, the comma in customerAddress2 cuts off DC. I tried a newcommand: `\newcommand{\safecomma}{,}` but this substitution happened immediately and the failure was the same. I tried the solution from [how to use special character in DTLloaddb keys](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57589/how-to-use-special-character-in-dtlloaddb-keys) (`\begingroup
\lccode`+`\%\lowercase{\endgroup\def\safepercent{+}}`) but, while that worked fine for the % sign, I couldn't figure out how to implement it for a comma.

Can this be done?

Comment: Have you tried `customerAddress2,"Washington, DC"`?

Comment: Wow. Nailed it. I tried it with single quotes, but not double, it appears. Thanks.